# Adding an excel command to open a csv file to the start of a relative path in HTML

Tags: html, excel, pytest, pytest-html

I'm currently using the [pytest-html](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html/) plugin to generate a test report in HTML. These HTML test reports will be put into a folder with related .csv files, and uploaded onto SharePoint for others to download and see. pytest-html allows me to add more HTML to the report generation, and I want to include a local file path link that automatically opens the excel file.

To open an excel file for editing through an HTML file path link, I add `ms-excel:ofe|u|` to the beginning. For example:

`'<a href="ms-excel:ofe|u|file:///d:/folder/aaa.csv">Open in Excel</a>'`

The command is perfectly fine with an absolute path, but what if I need to put it at the start of a relative path? For example:

`'<a href="ms-excel:ofe|u|./aaa.csv'`

In this case, excel tries to open a file literally named `./aaa.csv` and doesn't properly go into the relative path where the HTML file is located.

How can I directly open an excel file through a relative HTML file path link?

Comment: Have you tried `<a href="ms-excel:ofe|u|file:aaa.csv">Open in Excel</a>`?

Comment: I tried it but it just attempts to open a file named `file:aaa.csv` rather than getting the relative path.